# can't mount kobo libra 2 on osx

Tags: kobo

The reader shows up in Disk Utility, but with no free space (even after a factory reset). If I try to mount it I get the error `Could not mount “KOBOeReader”. (com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter error -119930872.)`

This happens on all USB ports and also while going through a hub. I can mount it just fine on a linux machine.

Comment: Have you tried installing Calibre, https://calibre-ebook.com/download_osx, and mounting it through that app?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are using your company's Mac. And due to security reasons, your company's policy banned usage of external devices.

I've encountered the exact same issue with the exact same error code 119930872. And I asked my company's IT support and they told me this